# NFS Share Permissions -Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: permissions, nfs

How can I ensure that:

- in NFS folders shared from machine-1, the directory creation mask is set to 600 or 622
- in NFS folder shared from machine-1 the file creation mask is set to 700 or 770